# Retaining form field and jQuery var values when browser Back button clicked

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a web project that is written using the following platform/technologies:

```
ASP.NET and MVC5/C#
.NET Framework 4.5.1
jQuery 2.1.1
jQuery UI 1.10.4
```

The app was written to be cross-browser compatible and responsive.

The application has several pages which contain many complex form fields used by engineers to input numeric values. These values are temperatures, fluid and air flow tolerances, heat dissipation limits, etc. There are many dropdowns that allow for selecting Unit of Measure (Centigrade/Fahrenheit, meters/feet per second and many others) for both input and output.

Upon selecting a Unit of Measure its associated form field values get converted and the form field value is converted/calculated/updated accordingly using jQuery events. The Unit of Measure selection is saved in a jQuery global var on that page.

The usual program flow would be for a user to enter their specifications and preferred UOM. Once the forms values are entered/converted, they are submitted using HTTP POST. A list of compatible products with abbreviated details are returned from the MVC controller in JSON format and displayed using jQuery DataTables.

The user can then select one of the products which causes navigation to a different MVC View that displays extensive details for the specified product along with optional accessories, pricing and shipping options, etc.

The client has decided they would like to retain the state of these form fields when a user clicks their browser's Back/Forward buttons. This seems like a daunting task to me. I am aware of using ASP.NET session variables, but I wanted to ask the developer community what the pros/cons are for implementing this kind of feature and what approaches are recommended.

Comment: A cookie might be more preferable since its stored on the client side and can be read/written to by javascript.  If the user uses a back button, there is a chance the server is never hit again, the page would just be loaded from the browser cache.  However, the javascript will still execute and be able to pull the cookie values for those fields.

Comment: @Tommy Didn't HTML5 implement a feature that saved form data? And since ASP uses cookies to save session variables might this work? Or are you recommending to save the cookies using jQuery on the client side? Sorry, I've just never been met with the challenge of saving complicated form data like this before.

Comment: ASP uses a cookie to store the session id, not the values in session, that is stored in the server memory typically.  As for HTML 5, they may have, but since most of my apps still need to support legacy browsers such as IE8, I don't have much experience in using those new features.  You can create/edit cookies from both the client and the server side by the way.  The client cannot access the session variables directly as they are stored on the server.

Comment: Sounds like you guys are talking about html5 localStorage. It actually has good browser support, even IE8. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: @ClaytonLeis Yes, localStorage is what I was thinking. Your link shows another option which may be more suitable - sessionStorage. I don't think we need to retain values after the browser is closed. I haven't ready the entire link yet, but I will. Given the complexity of these forms and the lack of design with this in mind I'm not sure if this will be straightforward to implement or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the Browser's sessionStorage.

On your form submit button (or event) store all the form data by calling
 `StoreFormValues($(#MyFormId"), "MyFormName" )`

When loading your page check if the page was navigated to via back button, if yes restore all the form data.

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 2) { // 2 means page was accessed by navigating into the history (Browser Back Button)
    RestoreFormValues($("#MyFormId"), "MyFormName");
}

function RestoreFormValues(form, name) {
    form.find(':input:visible').not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]').each(function () {
        var value = sessionStorage.getItem(name + $(this).prop('id'));
        if (value)
            $(this).val(value);
    });
}

function StoreFormValues(form, name) {
    form.find(':input:visible').not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]').each(function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem(name + $(this).prop('id'), value = $(this).val());
    });
}
```

MyFormName is just a name to uniquely prefix the field names in the session storage.